# Can I access 2 indices of an array at the same time VHDL

Tags: arrays, concatenation, vhdl, fpga

So if I have an output that is 16 bits and I want to concatenate every 2 indices of an 8 bit array to form a 16 bit output. Is it possible to access the array at the same time? Here is an example:

```
       Output : out std_logic_Vector(15 downto 0);
       .
       .
       .
       type array1 is array(0 to 5) of std_logic_Vector(7 downto 0);
       signal myarray : array1;
       .
       .
       .
```

assuming "myarray" is already filled with values can i do this and will it work fine when i synthesize?

```
 Output <= myarray(i) & myarray(k);
```

where i = 0 and k = 1 which get the first two indices of the array.

Comment: Most of the synthesizers will implement the array as ram and won't allow you to do that.

Comment: Block Rams in some (most?) FPGAs have dual port access options : different synthesis tools may or may not know how to synthesise to use dual port memory.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if the synth tools attempted to implement the array as a ram, given the size

Comment: @gsm so at what size would it attempt to implement the array as a ram? In the following user guide :https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/xst_v6s6.pdf they give that the following would model a RAM in vhdl:  (0 to 255)of std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); So would it have to be of that size ?

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler then the synthesis tool will fall back to simple registers. But they don't error out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is perfectly fine.

In you example, it's "just wires" so it is as efficient as any other (correct) syntax.

If you would register the array in a clocked process, the concatenation would just mean that you need to read the array twice in a clock cycle - the FPGA tools will most likely make the array using flip-flops in this case by default and with the sizes you indicated and with modern FPGAs that is perfectly fine as well.

For larger arrays, I wouldn't trust the tools, but make the memory access explicit; either two separate memory blocks or a memory block with twice as wide output than input.

Comment: well i do fill in the array with values in a clocked process, but after i fill it up i want to be able to send the output as i showed.